# Apache ZooKeeper Error status=1

Tags: mesos, marathon, apache-zookeeper

I am getting this error on my Mesos Master node.

Anyone know what it means and how to resolve it?

```
bash-4.2$ sudo systemctl status zookeeper
â— zookeeper.service - Apache ZooKeeper
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/zookeeper.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-08-24 01:44:31 EDT; 2s ago
  Process: 3164 ExecStart=/opt/mesosphere/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3164 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 24 01:44:31 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com systemd[1]: Unit zookeeper.service entered failed state.
Aug 24 01:44:31 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com systemd[1]: zookeeper.service failed.
```

sudo journalctl -u zookeeper

```
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: Using config: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: 2016-08-24 01:19:52,582 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@103] - Reading configuration from: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: 2016-08-24 01:19:52,587 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@340] - Defaulting to majority quorums
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: 2016-08-24 01:19:52,589 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: 2016-08-24 01:19:52,590 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: 2016-08-24 01:19:52,590 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: 2016-08-24 01:19:52,600 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerMain@127] - Starting quorum peer
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: 2016-08-24 01:19:52,610 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@94] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: 2016-08-24 01:19:52,611 [myid:1] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@89] - Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:95)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:130)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:111)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com zookeeper[382]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
Aug 24 01:19:52 scsor0004331001.rtp.openenglab.netapp.com systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you do a `sudo journalctl -u zookeeper` and paste the output into your question?

Comment: Looks like it says something is in use. how do i resolve that?

Comment: Do a `netstat -tulpn | grep :2181`. What's the output?

Comment: -bash-4.2$ netstat -tulpn | grep :2181
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      4552/java

Comment: Use `sudo` then...

Comment: um same thing.... tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      4552/java

Comment: You could try to kill the PID. Seems like there is already a ZooKeeper instance running. Did you start ZK manually?